# Connecting to On-Premises Oracle DB from Azure Data Factory

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory

Trying to connecting to On-Premises Oracle DB from Azure Data Factory.

Current Setup:

[image]

1. Oracle db - On Premises
2. VM with Self Hosted Integration Runtime on Azure - Tested with other MSSQL Server Databases - can connect successfully - This VM is managed by ITP (our Cloud Hosting Team), developers don't have access to it.
3. Azure Data Factory - configured to consume above Self Hosted Integration Runtime.

I can connect to Oracle db from my local machine, using Taod for Oracle.  When passed same credential details - connection fails from ADF.

Do I need to ask ITP to install ODAC on VM for the connectivity?

Comment: Is there a specific error message from ADF when connection fails? Are you using "Connection String" or "Azure Key Vault"? Is the connection type "Oracle SID" or "Oracle Service Name"?

Comment: Figured out, just need to install Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) on the VM and everything works.

Comment: Hi @Sreedhar, I help you post it as the answer that you have figured it out. You could think about mark it as answer to make others know your error is solved.  This can be beneficial to other community members. Or you could post it yourself, I will delete mine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations that @Sreedhar have figured out the error by himself:

"Figured out, just need to install Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) on the VM and everything works."

I help him post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.